# HTTPS for APIs : In Production

Tags: https, server, playframework-2.0

I am using Playframework for an API solution I have built.  There are no HTML Pages served by my server, only API query responses in JSON.  I know that playframework can support https with a self signed keys using **`Dhttps.port=9443`**.
It is written in the documentation that this is to be used only in Dev mode.

Since, I dont have webpages being served (and hence no browser warnings for self signed keys) and I am bothered only about encryption for API calls, can I use this for production too?  or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says that if you do not provide any certificate when you run the app in prod mode, Play will generate one and run it. This is discouraged because, the certificate is just a random stuff which you do not have any control on.

Coming to the question of using a private certificate, if you open the url in a browser, it warns the user of a "non-trusted-certificate". Since this is not the case with you and if your web server consumers are restricted to a confined set, I think you can use it in prod mode. Please consider other pros and cons of it too before proceeding.

In case you wish to go ahead, you can always generate a private certificate of your own and use it to run the app. Commands according to Play documentation for this are:

```
keytool -genkeypair -v \
-alias cert \
-dname "CN=<CHANGE ME>, OU=<CHANGE ME>, O=<CHANGE ME>, L=<CHANGE ME>, ST=<CHANGE ME>, C=IN" \
-keystore cert.jks \
-keypass a1AhzIabP1 \
-storepass a1AhzIabP1 \
-keyalg RSA \
-keysize 4096 \
-ext KeyUsage:critical="keyCertSign" \
-ext BasicConstraints:critical="ca:true" \
-validity 9999
```

Check the certificate using this command

```
keytool -list -v \
-keystore conf/cert.jks \
-storepass a1AhzIabP1
```

Then configure it in your application.conf like this

```
https.port=9443
play.server.https.keyStore.path="conf/cert.jks" # relative path to your certificate
play.server.https.keyStore.password="a1AhzIabP1"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  Are you aware of any other pros and cons of using a private certificate ?